# Multithreading to open file and update a class object

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I am creating Tasks using a for loop will those tasks run in parallel or would they just run one after the other?

Here is my code -

```
private void initializeAllSpas()
{
    Task[] taskArray = new Task[spaItems.Count];

    for(int i = 0; i < spaItems.Count; i++)
    {
        taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => spaItems[i].initializeThisSpa());
    }

    Task.WhenAll(taskArray).Wait();

    foreach (var task in taskArray) task.Dispose();
}
```

where `spaItems` is a list of items from another class, call it `SpaItem`, in which the `initializeThisSpa()` function opens a file and updates the information for that particular `SpaItem`.

My question is, does the above code actually excute `initializeThisSpa()` on all of the `spaItems` at the same time? if not, how can I correct that?

Comment: Seems like it would always going to execute `initializeThisSpa()` everytime.

Comment: The bottleneck is reading files from disk. While one thread reads a chunk of data from the disk, others will have to wait.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov so basically if I am handling opening files then it will work in sequence one after the other? What if those files are on a network location... same thing?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a [pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx). One thread reads the files and puts the data in the collection. Other(s) thread(s) use these data to initialize.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov the only issue with that for my case is that the files can't be read by a file stream, they are excel files. So I actually have to open excel to read the data from those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I Ignored syntax issues if any and not tested)

At the same time?..

Not guaranteed. At least (the best bet) definitely there will be nano secs difference.

Tasks are placed in a queue.

And every task waits for its opportunity for a thread from threadpool, for its turn of execution.

It all depends on the availability of threads in thread pool. If no thread available, the tasks waits in queue.

There are different states for the task before its final execution. Here is a good explanation. And after going through this link, you will come to know that it is almost impossible to call a function at the same time from multiple tasks.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/08/30/the-meaning-of-taskstatus/

You can achieve tasks sequentially (one after another) calling a specific function by creating tasks with methods like "ContinueWith, ContinueWhenAll, ContinueWhenAny,"

An example is below in MSDN documentation link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just want to make sure that in order for the next task to run ie- `i+1` it doesn't need to wait for the task started on `i`

Comment: Hmm.... This is some what merely guaranteed... but still there is uncertainity .... if you watch below statement from documentation carefully...     "Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been enhanced with algorithms that determine and adjust to the number of threads and that provide load balancing to maximize throughput."...........We do not know what algorithms they are using.... so still there is a chance of uncertainty